# Intelllij Single Jar (jar with dependencies) how not to include unused files NOT MAVEN

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am using `htmlunit` and `Apache POI` library which is total ~33mb. I am sure i am not using everything included in this libraries. So when i create single jar with dependencies i want to make it minimal as possible. But it gets all jars. How to make intellij include only used classes?

*NOT MAVEN*

Comment: Well, if you are using maven you could exclude something from dependencies https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: no i am using default ide tools

Comment: So I suggest you to use it, it will help you a lot with this dependencies managing. It took 10 mins to understand how to use it and makes you spent several time less.

Comment: How to migrate then?

Comment: Right-click on the module, select "Add framework support...", and check the "Maven" technology.